# Custom searching using tastypie

Tags: tastypie

actually we have 2 models

```
class Event(Basetable):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    event_description = models.TextField()
    image = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to=get_eventlogo_path, resize_source=dict(size=(700, 0), crop='smart'),)
    category = models.ManyToManyField("EventCategory")
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue,null=True)

class Venue(models.Model):
venue   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
address1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
address2 = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
slug = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True,null=True)
country = models.ForeignKey(Countries,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
state = models.ForeignKey(States,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
city = models.ForeignKey(City,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

tastypie code

```
class EventResource(ModelResource):
venue      = fields.ForeignKey(VenueResource, 'venue')    

class Meta:
    queryset = Event.objects.filter(status='P').order_by('-id').distinct()
    resource_name = 'eventlist'
    filtering = {
        "slug": ('exact', 'startswith',),
        "title": ALL,
    }
```

my problem is i need to get event result using city which is in venue

ex www.example.com/api/v1/eventlist/?format=json&city="chicago" but it is not coming help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to  allow filtering by venue:

```
filtering = { 'venue': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS

               }
```

This link will work.
www.example.com/api/v1/eventlist/?format=json&venue_*city*_name="chicago"

Comment: Lookups are not allowed more than one level deep it is showing this error

Comment: You should allow filtering in venue resource by city and CityResource by name